# Couchbase: How to create JsonObject from a string

Tags: java, json, couchbase

How to easily convert/parse the string representation of a JSON object into an instance of com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JsonTranscoder ([API document](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.0.1/com/couchbase/client/java/transcoder/JsonTranscoder.html)) to do this.

```
String rawJson = "{\"companyname\":\"Apple\",\"employees\":[{\"name\":\"Steve\",\"age\":48},{\"name\":\"Michael\",\"age\":39}]}";
JsonTranscoder trans = new JsonTranscoder();
JsonObject jsonObj = trans.stringToJsonObject(rawJson);
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 3):

*edit, short answer*: if you already have Json in String form I would just skip JsonObject and directly store the string via `RawJsonDocument` instead. If you want to make use of JsonObject to read/write fields in the Json between obtaining the string and storing it, see 
[Flame113's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27440801/1113486) (`JsonTranscoder`).

In Couchbase Java SDK 2.x, JsonObject is the class used to work with JSON, in a simplified way. You can use it to construct well-formed JSON, with a limited sub-set of types allowed in like this:

```
JsonObject myJson = JsonObject.create()
    .put("name", "bob")
    .put("age", 23)
    .put("role", "something");
```

Version 2.0.1 contains factory methods to create them from collections such as `JsonObject.from(Map<String, ?>)`.

Note that RawJsonDocument allows you to store/retrieve some raw JSON as Strings.
Support for String to JsonObject conversion via factory methods may come up in a future version, probably not before 2.1 though.

Comment: confirmed, feature will be in 2.1, as a factory method `fromJson`

Comment: do you know how this can be achieve in Couchbase-client 1.4.4?